# Permission denied for local pod installation

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have local pod for my app. And tried installing them into my pod file but they said permission denied. What might be the possible reason for that ? And where do we setup permission ?

[image]

```
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
      pod 'Fabric'
      pod 'A', :path => '../locationA'
      pod 'B', :path => '../locationB'
      pod 'C', :path => '../locationC'
      pod 'D', :path => '../locationD'

 end

 target 'test' do
   shared_pods
 end
```